# PHP get ranges of same values from array

Tags: php, arrays, key, range

Is there any way to get the key range of same values and make a new array?

Let's say we have an Array Like this in php :

```
$first_array = ['1'=>'a','2'=>'a','3'=>'a','4'=>'b','5'=>'b','6'=>'a','7'=>'a'];
```

How can i get this array? Is there any function for this?

```
$second_array = ['1-3'=>'a','4-5'=>'b','6-7'=>'a'];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: count a's in array, count b's in array. create new array

Comment: Are the `a`s always associated with consecutive numbers? If not, should the output reflect their appearance or "group" them no matter where they appear? Be more specific, please.

Comment: Is it the keys you want to group who have a specific value (or the same)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through it, extract the keys, generate the ranges and insert to the new array -

```
$first_array = ['1'=>'a','2'=>'a','3'=>'a','4'=>'b','5'=>'b'];

$flip = array();
foreach($first_array as $key => $val) {
  $flip[$val][] = $key;
}

$second_array = [];
foreach($flip as $key => $value) {
    $newKey = array_shift($value).' - '.end($value);
    $second_array[$newKey] = $key;
}
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["1 - 3"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["4 - 5"]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Comment: thanks.but it does not work correct for some array like this :$first_array = ['1'=>'a','2'=>'a','3'=>'a','4'=>'a','5'=>'a','6'=>'b','7'=>'b','8'=>'a','9'=>'a'];

Comment: Yo have add check for that.

Comment: As @Amirabbasasadi pointed out, this doesn't always work. I had the same problem. Check out my answer below.

Comment: This wont work for same values as array cannot have same key multiple time. In that case you have to use sub arrays.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your first question you can get range of each value using foreach() loop.

```
$first_array = ['1'=>'a','2'=>'a','3'=>'a','4'=>'b','5'=>'b'];

foreach($first_array as $key=>$value)
{
        //do your coding here, $key is the index of the array and $value is the value at that range, you can use that index and value to perform array manipulations
}
```

Regarding your second question it not exactly clear what are trying to implement there. But what ever you want to do like creating a new array with modified index and other things can be done within this `foreach()` loop itself

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for an answer, here is what I did.
Given the array

```
$first_array = ['0'=>'a',
                '1'=>'a',
                '2'=>'a',
                '3'=>'a',
                '4'=>'a',
                '5'=>'b',
                '6'=>'b',
                '7'=>'a',
                '8'=>'a']
```

I build a multidimensional array, in which each element is an array of three more elements:

```
[0] - The value in the first array
[1] - The key where the value starts repeating
[2] - The last key where the value stops repeating
```

The code

```
$arrayRange = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($first_array); $i++){

    if(count($arrayRange) == 0){
        // The multidimensional array is still empty
        $arrayRange[0] = array($first_array[$i], $i, $i);
    }else{
        if($first_array[$i] == $arrayRange[count($arrayRange)-1][0]){
            // It's still the same value, I update the value of the last key
            $arrayRange[count($arrayRange)-1][2] = $i;
        }else{
            // It's a new value, I insert a new array
            $arrayRange[count($arrayRange)] = array($first_array[$i], $i, $i);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get a multidimensional array like this:

```
$arrayRange[0] = array['a', 0, 4]; 
$arrayRange[1] = array['b', 5, 6];
$arrayRange[2] = array['a', 7, 8];
```